# How does a Pulsed Plasma Thuster work?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

My friend was describing a Pulsed Plasma Thruster (PPT) to me, and we couldn't figure out how it actually worked. The setup involves two conducting plates with a potential difference and a solid, insulating fuel block sandwiched in between.

[image]

From the Wikipedia page:

> The first stage in PPT operation involves an arc of electricity passing through the fuel, causing ablation and sublimation of the fuel. The heat generated by this arc causes the resultant gas to turn into plasma, thereby creating a charged gas cloud. Due to the force of the ablation, the plasma is propelled at low speed between two charged plates (an anode and cathode). Since the plasma is charged, the fuel effectively completes the circuit between the two plates, allowing a current to flow through the plasma. This flow of electrons generates a strong electromagnetic field which then exerts a Lorentz force on the plasma, accelerating the plasma out of the PPT exhaust at high velocity.

As I understand it, the current is directed vertically between the two plates, which creates a magnetic field in the horizontal direction - call it $x$ (left to right in the diagram). The electrons would seemingly then experience a Lorentz force in the $y$-direction (into the plane). What am I missing here? It seems in order for the plasma to be accelerated along $x$, we would need $\mathbf{B}$ directed along $y$.

Comment: Well, rotate the chamber by 90 degrees in the xy plane and it should drive the plasma in the direction you "expect" :-)

Comment: Glancing through, it appears to work the same way as a rail gun, replacing the metal projectile with a plasma. I'll look again on my lunch break.

Comment: Ah okay. Dumb of me. The arcing happens in the $yz$ plane, and current flows along this sheet, creating a $\mathbf{B}$ field in the $y$-direction, so the Lorentz force is indeed in $x$. Thanks!

Comment: When plasma is pulled by the magnetic field created by the current in the plasma, where does the plasma move? Nowhere.

Comment: @user7027 if plasma is pulled by a magnetic field, it moves in the direction the field pulls it. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @Asher Plasma can pull itself by its magnetic field, but that does not cause the plasma to move. That a Newton's law.

Comment: Wrong: Put a moving charge in a magnetic field, measure magnetic field, calculate that Lorenz-force is q*v*B   Correct: measure magnetic field, put a moving charge in that magnetic field, calculate that Lorenz-force is q*v*b

Comment: The plasma does not have a magnetic field. The ions are responding to the field generated by the moving electrons.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Does the plasma thruster thrust out plasma? Is plasma made of ions and electrons?

Comment: @user7027 it's not a Newtonian law that plasma can't move in a magnetic field. The plasma can't move *itself* anywhere, but it's part of a system and the system can do work on the plasma. That doesn't break any more laws than a regular chemical fuel rocket.

Comment: @Asher That was my answer with which the OriginalPoster disagreed. From somewhere the Poster got very incorrect ideas about how the machine works. See my answer. Maybe you could somehow help there. For example by saying "user7027 is right, pay attention to what user7027 says"  :)

Comment: You'll note that my question was about the direction of the Lorentz force, not about whether the moving charges create a magnetic field or whether there is a force on the particles. Those facts I already state in my question details. So you didn't answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

The current in the plates creates a magnetic field, the charges in the plasma move in that magnetic field. That causes a Lorenz-force on the particles.

Comment: There is no current in the plates. The plasma provides a conductive path between the plates, which causes electrons to flow from one plate to the other. The flow of electrons generates a magnetic field, which in turn exerts a force on the plasma. I wrote the answer in a comment.

Comment: Let's consider a tram overhead wire and and tram rail. We put a metal rod between the wire and the rail. To which direction does the rod start to move? For example does it start to move along the rail or sideways? Can anybody here answer that very simple question?